# Calculating Variance Explained from PCA Loadings

Tags: variance, pca, factor-loading

I have a return history for a universe of risky assets and I've run a principal component algorithm and obtained a loadings matrix (num_factors by num_assets) for the first 5 factors.

I have a portfolio as well (a subset of the above universe) with weights w for each of the assets.  This portfolio has a variance \sigma^2.  How do I figure out the percentage of the variance in the portfolio that comes from factor 1?

Comment: The algorithms usually give it to you as one of the outputs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PCA gives you a decomposition of the covariance matrix of the form
$$
\Sigma = V \Lambda V^T
$$
where $\Lambda$ is diagonal with the eigenvalues in the diagonal.
Your portfolio variance is
$$
w^T \Sigma w = (V^T w )^T \Lambda (V^T w)
$$
On the other hand if you take your return matrix $R$ and define 
$$
F = V^T R
$$
then the covariance matrix of these so called principle portfolios is $\Lambda$.
You find this [here by Meucci](http://www.cass.city.ac.uk/__data/assets/pdf_file/0003/213699/Meucci-ReDefining-and-Managing-Diversification.pdf).

In fact he writes $V^{-1} R$ for the return of principle portfolios
and defines the weights $w^* = V^{-1} w$ for the weight of the original portfolio on the principle portfolios.

He then defines $v_n = (w^*)^2 \lambda_n^2$ for the contribution of the n-th principle portfolio to the portfolio variance. If you relate this to the total volatility of the portfolio then you are done. Note that $V$ is orthogonal which means that $V^{-1} = V^T$.

I recommend to read the following [white paper](http://www.lyxor.com/publications/white-papers/wp/82/) or [this blog entry](http://systematicedge.wordpress.com/2013/06/02/principal-component-analysis-in-portfolio-management/) or [this](http://www.northinfo.com/documents/515.pdf) to get more details.

Comment: Thanks Richard.  The links were especially helpful.  Using the links I was able to determine that you can get the $v_n$ above using $v_n = (Lw)^2$ where $L$ is the loadings matrix and the results is the same as using $(w^*)^2 \lambda_n^2$.